# libreadline - unmet dependecies/broken package

Tags: 16.10

Error message:

`libreadline6-dev` : Depends: libreadline6 (= 6.3-8ubuntu2) but 6.3-8ubuntu8 is to be installed`

This is a little bit mental as I have no trouble installing `libreadline6`, but the '-dev' package fails with this error.

UPDATE:

```
libreadline6-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6.3-8ubuntu2
  Version table:
    6.3-8ubuntu2 500
      500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What is your version of Ubuntu?

Comment: the version is 16.10 , as the tag :D

Comment: Right. That's weird because `libreadline6-dev` does not exist in 16.10, which uses readline 7. What's the output of `apt-cache policy libreadline6-dev`?

Answer (score 3):

The package `libreadline6-dev` does not exist in Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety) since the default version of readline is now 7. (More precisely, it still exists [as a virtual package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libreadline6-dev), but for our purposes here it might as well not exist at all.)

However, on your system you still have some Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) sources enabled, and since `libreadline6-dev` does exist in Xenial, your system tries to install it from there. And this fails, because even though Yakkety does not have `libreadline6-dev`, it does have `libreadline6`, but the Yakkety version of `libreadline6` cannot be installed together with the Xenial version of `libreadline6-dev`.

How to proceed from there depends on what you want to do, which you have not mentioned. However, unless you really need readline 6, you can just install `libreadline-dev` (which will install readline 7). You very probably also want to remove those Xenial sources from your `sources.list`, since they interfere with your package management in ways you probably don't want.

Comment: it's a requirement for installing ruby via rvm and in general packages that use libreadline, it's asking explicitly for `libreadline6-dev`, tried with 7 but I got no candidate for it `libreadline7-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
`

Comment: @decebal Sorry, the package name is just `libreadline-dev`.

Comment: @decebal did you ever get this resolved? (I also am having trouble installing ruby via rvm)

Comment: @Gschneider I just installed `libreadline-dev` and seemed to do the job

Comment: Thanks! That didn't work for me, but I was able to change `requirements_check libreadline6-dev` to `requirements_check libreadline-dev` in  `.rvm/scripts/functions/requirements/ubuntu` and it seemed to work.

Comment: This happened because newer Ubuntu releases libreadline7-dev and made libreadline6-dev as a virtual package provided by `libreadline-dev`. Latest rvm uses this `libreadline-dev` instead which fixed the problem